# TypeError with HTML Element array

Tags: javascript, types, compiler-errors, typeerror

Running the following code :

```
function inc_value_pvt()
{
    var max = 0;
    var pvtStunden = document.getElementsByName('pvtStunden');

    for(var i=0; i<=pvtStunden.length; i++)
    {
        max += parseInt(pvtStunden[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('stunden').value = max;
}
```

I always get this error message:

> TypeError: pvtStunden[i] is undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: TypeError variable is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586064/javascript-typeerror-variable-is-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

You are looping for one extra time.

`for(var i=0; i<pvtStunden.length; i++)`